# Conv2d and the value of padding

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to ask about the value of padding we set in the [Conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) function.

I know what zero-padding is. However, what does it mean that the padding is 0 for instance, or 1,2, or 3. What do these values mean? Do they represent the number of columns and rows that will be filled with zeros?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the anchor point for a particular convolution kernel causes some of the kernel weights to fall outside the image then those anchor points won't be placed in the final output. So for example with a kernel size of 3, without padding the edges will be removed since the kernel would extend past the edge of the image here. A good rule of thumb is to use `padding=(kernel_size-1)/2` at least for odd kernel sizes since this will ensure the edges can be included as anchors (this gets a little more complicated if you start playing with dilation)

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states:

> `padding` controls the amount of implicit zero-paddings on both sides for padding number of points for each dimension.

Therefore, `padding=1` means you pad your input with 1 column and row from each size.
If you want more control over the amount of padding and its value you can either use a [`Padding`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#padding-layers) layer, or the [`pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pad) functional.